# ¿Cómo hacer control de fallos usando PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy pasando de usar la función mysqli_connect a PDO pero tengo algunas dificultades al momento de gestionar errores en mis queries
Al momento de hacer una consulta select, si estoy usando mysqli en un archivo llamado **test.php**

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$usr,$pdw,$db);
$query="SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM caducidadLote";  
$r=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Al correrlo en el navegador me dice que la tabla no existe, lo cual esta bien, ya que el nombre de la tabla está mal escrito. Pero al momento de implementarlo en pdo tengo lo siguiente

archivo: **conexionBD.php**

```
class conectar_db{   
    public static function crearConexion(){
        $host="nombre_host";
        $user="usuario_bd";
        $password="contra_bd";
        $database="nombre_bd";
        try{
            $opciones=array(
                   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true,
                   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
            );
            $conexión= new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.";dbname=".$database,$user,$password,$opciones);
            return $conexion;
        }catch(PDOException $error){
            echo "Error: ".$error->getMessage();
        }
       
        
   }
}
```

Después ese archivo lo mando a llamar en otro archivo

archivo: **test2.php**

```
require_once('/var/www/conexionBD.php');
$conectar=new conectar_db; //clase
$conexion=$conectar->crearConexion(); //function
$query="SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM caducidadLote"; //el error es el mismo el nombre de la tabla esta mal
$resul=$conexión->prepare($query);
$resul->execute();
$array=$resul->fetch();
echo print_r($array);
```

Cuando hago la prueba en el navegador me sale el siguiente error

[image: Error del navegador]

Existe alguna forma de que en lugar de ese error anterior me salga un mensaje como el de la imagen siguiente? Ya que en este caso se cual es el error, pero en futuros queries algún error de dedo, o de nombres puede hacer que me muestre el de "Esta página no esta disponible" pero en realidad eso no es muy útil

[image: error segundo]

Espero haber sido claro, y gracias de antemano por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás teniendo un error con respecto al código en el núcleo mismo de PHP y el mismo escapa a una lógica de manejo de errores, es decir, el código no falla porque el nombre de la tabla es incorrecto, sino porque estás llamando mal al método `crearConexion()`. La solución es corregir la sintaxis de tu código.

Si observas `crearConexion()` ha sido declarado como `static`, por tanto, puedes hacer la llamada sin instanciar la clase.

Luego, para controlar el otro error (el del nombre de la tabla), en PDO puedes hacerlo en un bloque `try ... catch`, porque PDO, a diferencia de mysqli, posee manejo de excepciones.

Aplicando lo dicho, tu código quedaría así:

```
require_once('/var/www/conexionBD.php');
/*
  Dado que crearConexion() es static
  puedes llamarlo simplemente con la notación
  nombreDeLaClase::metodoEstatico()
*/
$conexion=conectar_db::crearConexion(); //function

/*
  Y para controlar todos los errores
  en lo que es el manejo de la consulta
  puedes hacerlo con try ... catch en PDO
  porque el mismo incropora manejo de excepciones
*/
try {
    $query="SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM caducidadLote";     //el error es el mismo el nombre de la tabla esta mal
    $resul=$conexión->prepare($query);
    $resul->execute();
    $array=$resul->fetch();
    var_dump($array);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    /*
      ATENCIÓN: No se debería mostrar 
      errores internos en producción
      puede ser peligroso en algunos casos
      porque se podría mostrar en pantalla información sensible
      como la constraseña de la base de datos u otros ...
    */
    printf("ERROR: %s",$e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: *mysqli* sí maneja [excepciones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php), sólo hay que [activarlas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) en PHP < 8.

Comment: @Sal gracias por el dato. Lo que me refieres es propio de mysqli o de mysqlnd?